# Avoiding timeouts in Angular applications

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem that I was able to solve, using a timeout. This feels like a very bad practice that could lead to an unmaintainable mess, and I am looking for a better way to solve this problem.

Any ideas?

[A hopefully self-explanatory JSFiddle of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/zorro/Dkb5c/)

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<form name="form">
    <input custom-validation type="text" ng-model="model" name="text" /> 
it should not allowed to send the word 'fail'
</form>
<button ng-click="fillAndSend()">Fill with 'fail' and send</button>
<button ng-click="send()">Send</button>
 <h1>Success: {{success}}</h1>
```

```
angular.module('test', []);
angular.module('test').directive('customValidation', function () {
    'use strict';
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (value) {
                if (value == 'fail') {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('customValidation', false);
                } else {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('customValidation', true);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});

angular.module('test').controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.success = false;
    $scope.model;
    $scope.fillAndSend = function() {
        $scope.model = 'fail';
        $scope.send();
        /* using a timeout works
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.send();    
        },0);
        */
    }

    $scope.send = function () {
        if ($scope.form.$valid) {
            $scope.success = true;
        } else {
            $scope.success = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is because the angular $digest cycle is happening just once here.  Using the $timeout, forces the second part of what you do into a second digest cycle, which is why it works with the $timeout.  You can't just call `$scope.$apply()` because you are already in a digest cycle.  In this case, using the timeout is the correct thing to do because you need angular to realize the model changed, and THEN call the send function.

The other option is to set a flag in the controller that send is needing to be called since you are changing the model.  And then in your directive where you watch the model you could check to see if you need to call send

Comment: Some async services and providers use the built-in `$timeout` to trigger the $digest cycle. It's a neat trick and there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score -1):

scope.$apply() may help :

```
 $scope.fillAndSend = function() {
    $scope.model = 'fail';
    $scope.$apply();
    $scope.send();
    /* using a timeout works
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.send();    
    },0);
    */
}
```