# Is there a way besides $timeout to get a second digest to run in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

I am writing an attribute directive where if a variable is set, it adds the disabled attribute to ALL inputs and buttons, essentially making a form read only.  This is a feature request... The form is for expired data, but the client wants to see it if they need to.

Anyway, I have some input and buttons on the view, and there are some custom directives i've written that contain inputs, select,  and buttons.  For some reason, no matter what, I cannot get the attribute directive i'm working on to .find() the inputs and selects in my custom directives unless I use a $timeout for the .find().  Here is what I have so far. It works, but i know my coworkers will balk at using $timeout.

```
'use strict';
angular.module('induction').directive('sttiDisabled',['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var hello = function () {
                var formControls = angular.element(elem.querySelectorAll('input, select, button'));
                for (var i = 0; i < formControls.length; i++) {
                    var el = angular.element(formControls[i]);
                    el.attr('disabled', scope.ceremony.locked);
                    console.log(el);
                };
            };

            // Don't judge. It works flawlessly.
            var promise = $timeout(hello, 0);


        }
    }
}]);
```

You use it something like this:

```
<div stti-disabled>
<input ng-model="blah" />
<select ng-model="blah2" />
<custom-directive-containing-an-input> </that>
</div>
```

If scope.ceremony.locked===true, the input and select will be disabled , but not the input in the custom directive... UNLESS I use timeout.

EDIT: Probably a dupe of [Avoiding timeouts in Angular applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411549/avoiding-timeouts-in-angular-applications) but i'd like to open the question again, since things may have changed since 2014.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

To disable all of the inputs in a group, use the [ng-disabled directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) with the [`<fieldset>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset):

```
<fieldset ng-disabled="formDisable">
   <input ng-model="blah" />
   <select ng-model="blah2" 
          ng-options="name for name in [1,2,3]">
   </select>
   <custom-directive-containing-an-input> 
   </custom-directive-containing-an-input>
   <br>input = {{blah}}
   <br>select = {{blah2}}
   <br>disable = {{formDisable}}
</fieldset>
<input type=checkbox ng-model="formDisable"/>Disable form
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/RahNbe9koNnbZOQvlgAq?p=preview)

---

Did you try:

```
  scope.$watch("ceremony.locked", hello);
```

For more information on the scope methods, see [AngularJS scope API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

**Update**

Your method of using `$timeout` to invoke your "hello" method aynchronously doesn't work **flawlessly**; it works **fragilely**. What happens if you sprinkle your application with more `$timeout`s? You don't get a guarantee of the order in which the functions are invoked.

By using `$watch`, you get a guarantee that your 'hello' function gets invoked when the scope variable of interest is initialized and when it changes.

Comment: ceremony.locked won't get changed on the fly.  Its set before you ever get to any of the pages.. ceremony is a rootscope object. I add locked = true to it when i want the user to not be able to edit forms.  I pretty sure the watch will never fire, but i'll give it a try.