# Angular directive not working after route change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

Being fairly new to Angular I am currently building an app using angular and [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org) trying to write my first directive I ran into some trouble.

What I want to do: Have a card on the page with a toolbar at the top of it. Once the toolbar gets scrolled to the top of the screen it will "stick" there. To accomplish this behaviour I wrote a simple directive.

```
app.directive("sticky", function() {

return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      //"content" is the container in which my app scrolls.
      var content = document.getElementById('content');
      angular.element(content).bind("scroll", function() {

        var cardOffset = element[0].parentElement.offsetTop;
        var scrolled = content.scrollTop;
        var cardHeight = element[0].parentElement.clientHeight;
        var bottomOffset = cardOffset + cardHeight;

        //Check if we are currently scrolling through this element.
        if (scrolled >= cardOffset && scrolled <= bottomOffset) {
          element[0].style.top = (scrolled - cardOffset) + 'px';
          scope.shadow = true;
        } else {
          scope.shadow = false;
        }
        if (scrolled <= cardOffset) {
          element[0].style.top = '0px';
        }

      });
  }
}

});
```

Here is a [plunker of that in action](https://plnkr.co/edit/ERqOg43NbuNs5nSThaeM?p=preview). As you may notice the plunker works just as I described above.

However when I put this into my application I get the following weird behaviour: when visiting a view that contains a sticky element, said element doesn't have the sticky behaviour. 
My initial guess was something wrong with the $routeProvider, but as the plunker illustrates it works with that.

I am really lost and searching for ideas I can look into, to fix my problem.

Comment: Downloaded your code as it is. Sticky behavior working as expected in Safari and Firefox. What browser do you use?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough in my post. While it is working as intended in the plunker I get issues when actually using it in my app. Am simply stuck with no ideas what to look into.

Comment: I got that part, I tested it directly in browser (no plunker involved, I've downloaded raw files)

Comment: It was something else in my larger app messing it up. As solution below found, my JS code was being executed before the DOM for a view had been loaded. Resulting in the directive not working. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kinds of issues usually occur because the DOM hasn't fully loaded before the JS is being run. If you add a $timeout around your element then it works without issue.

See edited plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/xyjNRuEpRQ09KFHFcHjx?p=preview

```
app.directive("sticky", ['$timeout', function($timeout) {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $timeout(function() {
        var content = document.getElementById('content');
        angular.element(content).bind("scroll", function() {

          var cardOffset = element[0].parentElement.offsetTop;
          var scrolled = content.scrollTop;
          console.log(scrolled);
          var cardHeight = element[0].parentElement.clientHeight;
          var bottomOffset = cardOffset + cardHeight;

          //Check if we are currently scrolling through this element.
          if (scrolled >= cardOffset && scrolled <= bottomOffset) {
            element[0].style.top = (scrolled - cardOffset) + 'px';
            scope.shadow = true;
          } else {
            scope.shadow = false;
          }
          if (scrolled <= cardOffset) {
            element[0].style.top = '0px';
          }

        });
      }, 0);
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, works like a charm and I get the reasoning behind this. Is there more of an angular way to do this though? like an event I could listen for?

Comment: Looks like timeout is actually the way to go, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411549/avoiding-timeouts-in-angular-applications. Also tried "$locationChangeSuccess" and "$routeChangeSuccess" with no success. So timeout seems to be the way.